# How to use alternate flush mode on toilet

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet, plumbing-fixture

I have a Gerber toilet, and the toilet lists two flush modes. Do I need to install something to use that alternate flush mode? The toilet handle seems to have only one action.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have your model numbers?

Answer (score 12):

It's not an alternate mode, per se. Those values are the minimum and maximum tank volumes based on float setting. [Correction: These values seem to apply to High Efficiency (HE) and Ultra-high Efficiency (UHE) bowl/valve options. Since the values are printed on the bowl, they don't tell you much about the particular tank installed. However, the stamp in your bowl *does* indicate which you have (1.6 gpf).]

Your toilet is no different from all those that came before in the sense that when you lift the flappy-doodle with the levery-bit all the water falls out. They're rather unintelligent devices.

To reduce flush volume, adjust the float to a lower level. There's probably an [adjustment screw](https://youtu.be/NdTfggeTKFg?t=33) on it where you can move it down. This shuts off the water sooner on fill.

Comment: I think "uncomplicated" is better than unintelligent - I happen to think that simplicity is quite intelligent when it is the solution that best fits the problem!

Comment: Intelligence in a machine refers to its ability to react to different operating conditions. It's not a commentary on cleverness of design or degree of utility.

Comment: Indeed.  A smart design != a smart device.

Comment: Can also drop a water-filled bottle into the cistern to take up volume without contributing to the flush.

Answer (score 4):

When I look at the Gerber website, the only models I see with both the 1.6 and 1.28 designation are bowls (which is where your stamp seems to be).  Ex: https://www.gerber-us.com/product/north-point-1-28-or-1-6-gpf-elongated-top-spud-bowl/

But all the paired units appear to be either 1.6 or 1.28.  So it looks like you have an assembled 1.6 gpf toilet that cannot be changed to a 1.28 gpf one just by modifying the valve.

It doesn't appear the 1.28 gpf tanks are significantly different (they don't seem to have special valves), so you may be able to just lower the water level and get most of the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your flush valve (and handle) has been replaced with one that does not have the two settings. For the dual flush units, the handles is either split in two, like a long handle for the lighter flush and a short one for the full flush, or they have an Up-Down action; lift up for one, push down for the other (this is what I have seen in Gerber dual flush toilets).. The valve itself is very different though and that's not what you have in the tank, that looks like a standard single flush valve. So the original dual flush valve either broke/wore out or the original owner didn't like it and replaced it with an off-the-shelf single flush unit from a hardware store.

Comment: Do those toilets also have a different flap/drain mechanism? I'm not sure how it could be dual-flush otherwise.

Comment: It looks like you can convert them to dual flush https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMa8hur4XhM

Answer (score 1):

I've the same set up. I think it also has something to do with the flapper. On mine (had it apart to fix a leak) I noticed when you flush and release, the flapper drops a little earlier than full drain. If you hold the lever it empties completely. So 1.28 gallons from the 1.6 cut short, or held down for the full 1.6.

Gerber didn't have any info, but from observing the insides myself, if this is the case it seems to make sense. Or it could just be a coincidence and a wonky flapper on mine.

Comment: My does the same thing. It has to do with the tightness of the chain from flapper o handle. Taunt equals full flush, slack equals partial flush, hold down equals full flush.